# R: count elements in vector. Count() doesn't work

Tags: r, count

Does anyone know a function that counts the number of observations in a vector? And gives me the right number of emoji's? the function count() does not work.

Thankyou!

Comment: Please share a part of `Emoji` using `dput(head(Emoji, 30))`. Please _edit_ your question and put the `structure()`-output there.

Comment: Like this? @MartinGal

Comment: No. Your data.frame should be named `Emoji`. So please type `dput(head(Emoji, 30))` in R.

Comment: I changed it. This is what I get when putting in that

Comment: Thank you, that's much better since we can now easily reproduce your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Emoji %>%  
  unnest(emoji) %>% 
  count(id) %>% 
  right_join(Emoji, by = "id") %>% 
  arrange(id)
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 30 x 5
      id     n text                                                                            emoji   emoji_name
   <int> <int> <chr>                                                                           <list>  <list>    
 1     1    NA "yzy foam runner mx cream clay available august   httpstcopzsxngplbu  confirme~ <NULL>  <NULL>    
 2     2     1 "still original \U0001f9e0\n\n celebrate  year anniversary  nerdarmy’s debut a~ <chr [~ <chr [1]> 
 3     3    NA "introducing flexpark  swimwear collection created  confidently flex  day  sum~ <NULL>  <NULL>    
 4     4    NA "creativity     side  inspiration \n\nfeel  spirit  openness  slowthai  beabad~ <NULL>  <NULL>    
 5     5    NA "slowthai  beabadbee stay open   classic silhouette refreshed   bold new color~ <NULL>  <NULL>    
 6     6    NA "filmed   cotswolds  abbeyroad soundtracked  castofficials john power embark  ~ <NULL>  <NULL>    
 7     7    NA " open mind can take    path  anywhere \n\nsee  itsjeremyscott  waffle crew ex~ <NULL>  <NULL>    
 8     8    NA "fueled   passion  sport  adidasforprada ap luna rossa  brings primegreen  ser~ <NULL>  <NULL>    
 9     9    NA " open mind   way  life one  itsjeremyscott  kidthewiz live  \n\nwelcome  open~ <NULL>  <NULL>    
10    10    NA "   open mind take  \n\nshare  creativity   replies   chance  get  exclusive e~ <NULL>  <NULL>    
# ... with 20 more rows
```

So in column `n` you find the counted numbers of emojis.

Comment: Thanks! It gives me an error: `Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"`. Any idea what to do to fix it?

Comment: Are you using the `plyr`-package?

Comment: Im now using dplyr, which you said. Should I use plyr?

Comment: I was using plyr for something else as well in the same program btw.

Comment: Try unloading `plyr`, I think there are some incompabilities.